# how to read strings with commas by omitting them %[^,] not working for me

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf, calloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <crtdbg.h>  // needed to check for memory leaks (Windows only!)
#endif

#define FLUSH while(getchar() != '\n')

// Prototype Declarations
int readFile(FILE* ifp,char** words);

int main (void)
{
//  Local Definitions
FILE *ifp;
FILE *ofp;
char fnamer[100]="";
char **words;
int *freq;
int i;
int numWords =0;

//  Statements

    words = (char**)calloc (1001, sizeof(int));
        if( words == NULL )
        {
            printf("Error with Calloc\n");
            exit(111);
        }


  if (!(ifp=fopen("/Users/r3spectak/Desktop/song_row.txt", "r")))
  {
      printf("sucks");
      exit(100);
  }

    numWords = readFile(ifp,words);

    printf("%d", numWords);

    for(i=0;i<numWords;i++)
    printf("\n%s",words[i]);

    #ifdef _MSC_VER
    printf( _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() ? "Memory Leak\n" : "No Memory Leak\n");
    #endif
    printf("\n\t\tEnd of Program\n");
    printf("\n\t\tHave a great day!\n");
   return 0;

}


/*===============readFile=================
Pre:
Post:
This function
*/

int readFile(FILE* ifp,char** words)
{

// Local Variables
char buffer[1000] = " ";
int numWords = 0;

// Statements
while (fscanf(ifp," %s",buffer)!=EOF)
    {
    words[numWords] = (char*)calloc(strlen(buffer)+1,sizeof(char));
                if( words[numWords] == NULL)
                {
                    printf("\n");
                    exit(111);
                }
                strcpy(words[numWords],buffer);
                numWords++ ;
    }

return numWords;

}
```

The input file contains the following :
Row, row, row your boat,
Gently down the stream.
Merrily, merrily, merrily, merrily,
Life is but a dream.

After fscanf my array prints

```
  Row,
    row,
    row
    your
    boat, and so on
```

what i want is,

```
Row
row
row
your
boat
```

i've tried %[^,.\n] and its not working for me. it prints rubbish

Comment: So are you trying to comma-separate the input string?

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `calloc()` in a C program.

Comment: @H2CO3 im trying not to read the commas at all.

Comment: @CarlNorum i dont understand what you mean.

Comment: @KexyKathe Carl Norum means [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @KexyKathe So you want an array of strings from the original string, with boundaries specified by the commas, or you just want to eliminate the commas from the string?

Comment: @H2CO3 read each word into the array omitting the commas. eliminate the commas and fullstops. if i were to use malloc all the other elements wont be set to null right?

Comment: @KexyKathe Your second question makes no sense, but anyway... Why don't you copy over all characters to the other string *except commas and dots?*

Comment: @H2CO3 how exactly am i supposed to do that? im super lost.

Comment: @KexyKathe `while (*original) { if (*original != ',') { *copy++ = *original++; } }`

Comment: H2CO3's answer will work (it should be an answer) or you could look up strtok(). I http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Answer (score 0):

You might find [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) function especially useful. It will split your string into tokens, like the C equivalent of `split()` or `explode()`.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
  char str[] ="Row, row, row your boat, Gently down the stream.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.");
  while (pch != NULL){
     printf ("%s\n",pch);
     pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I basically copied the man page example. Calling the function again with the first argument as NULL will bring up the next string token.